# Install of update for KB2667402 fails with error 8024200D

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm working on a Windows 7 Home Premium system (64-bit) with Service Pack 1 installed.  Windows update is trying to install an update for KB2667402, but it's failing with error 8024200D.

A quick search turns up suggestions to run `sfc /scannow` (as administrator). I did that and it reports 'Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations'.

What's the trick to get this installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/237119-how-delete-uninstall-failed-unsuccesful-updates-window-7-a.html) thread.  Sure enough, an update for KB2667402 was already installed.  I uninstalled that and the new update installed without a problem.  System is now up to date with no pending installs.

Comment: Do you mean *update for KB2667402 was already* **installed**? instead of **uninstalled** ?

Comment: Was lazy, that would have meant I would have to read the linked article, as my edit would have changed the meaning of your post considerably.